# How to refactor my for loop as python dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using Python 3.6. I wrote following code, it's a for loop:

**Edit**: I made a mistake when I wrote var l down, so I re-type it here. Thanks for @Ender Look ！！

```
l = [['a','1'], ['a','2'], ['a','3']]
d = {}
for i in l:
    d[i[0]] = d.get(i[0], '') + '\t' + i[1]
print (d)
```

So, the result is what I want:
**{'a': '\t1\t2\t3'}**

Then I refactor above code as comprehension:

`dict2 = {}
dict2 = {i[0]: dict2.get(i[0], '') + '\t' + i[1] for i in l}
print(dict2)`

I though they should return same output. But the dict2 is:

**{'a': '\t3'}**

I want to know what's the matter with my dict comprehension? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your first code produce as output: `{'a': '\t1\t2'}` not `{'a': '\t1\t2\t3'}` as you said.

Comment: No. In your second example `dict2` is always the empty dict.

Comment: @Ender Look Opps! When I wrote my code here, I made some mistakes. I will edit it! Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried again, the output is still {'a': '\t3'}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily *need* to use a comprehension here. You can make use of `defaultdict` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(str)
>>> for li in l:
...  d[li[0]] += f'\t{li[1]}'
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'a': '\t1\t2'})
```

Comment: @U9-Forward I disagree with that being a reason do downvote someone. Providing a different solution is perfectly acceptable. Especially when there is a perfectly fine alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary comprehension doesn't work because it's use `.get` on itself.

```
dict2 = {i[0]: dict2.get(i[0], '') + '\t' + i[1] for i in l}
```

Until the end of the whole dictionary comprehension, this new dictionary isn't assigned to your actual `dict2` variable. So all the times your comprehension tries to retrieve the value from `dict2.get(...)` it always executes that function from the empty dictionary `dict2 = {}`.

Sadly, I don't know (and I don't think it exists) a way to use `.get` on a dictionary comprehension about itself, because the variable `dict2` isn't updated on "real time" (it wait until the end the comprehension). Or at least that I have understood, my humble knowledge isn't perfect.

Comment: Wonderful elusidation! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as a single dict comprehension.

```
{k: v
 for d in [{}]
 for k, v in [d.__setitem__(k, d.get(k, '') + '\t' + v) or d 
              for k, v in [['a','1'], ['a','2'], ['a','3']]][-1].items()}
```

You shouldn't.

Note how we had to create a reference to an inner dict `d` anyway, since your algorithm has to look things up in the dict *as it's being constructed*. What is the outer comprehension even *for*? And we're throwing away all but the last element of the inner list comp.

It's much clearer to use a normal for loop like this,

```
d = {}
for k, v in [['a','1'], ['a','2'], ['a','3']]:
    d[k] = d.get(k, '') + '\t' + v
```

Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Very helpful! I learn much from you. I appreciate it. But I want to know if my list l is a very large object. Would the loop reduce the efficiency?

Comment: @ywan would which loop reduce the efficiency compared to what?